# libpng in golang package

Tags: go, cgo

I need to import [this](https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo) package.

It require zlib and libpng.

I compile zlib and libpng by MinGW (my OS - Windows 8.1 64).

`libpng.a` now in MinGW lib folder, but nothin changed, same arror:

```
In file included from ./bitmap/../base/io_c.h:4:0,
             from ./bitmap/goBitmap.h:25,
             from ..\github.com\go-vgo\robotgo\robotgo.go:26:
./bitmap/../base/png_io_c.h:4:17: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory
#include <png.h>
```

Comment: Did you set your CPATH and LIBRARY_PATH environment vairables for GCC? Because it looks like it just can't find png.h in any of the folders it knows to look in; even though you've compiled libpng it still needs the header files at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mingw](https://github.com/go-vgo/Mingw) or read [this](https://github.com/go-vgo/Mingw32).

Comment: Please add some explanation of what your links are doing. Links can disappear, and if so, this answer would be worthless.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use these steps

1. download Mingw from https://github.com/go-vgo/Mingw
2. Set Environment set environment variables C:\Mingw\bin
3. Download win32 https://github.com/go-vgo/Mingw32
4. copy win32 inside the file (don't copy win32 folder) to 
   Mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include
5. Download zlib from  https://zlib.net/
6. use command 
       1) copy win32\makefile.gcc Makefile.gcc
       2)  mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc
7. copy libz.a to Mingw/lib
8. Download libpng from http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html
9. generate libpng.a and copy to Mingw/lib using command 1) copy scripts\makefile.gcc makefile.gcc 2) mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc